# TypeError: $(…).datatable is not a function

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have been reading about this, but I did not find my problem.

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../DataTables/datatables.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/rock-paper-scissosrs.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/rock-paper-scissosrs.css">
</head>
<body>
  <section>
    <article>
      <div id="scoreBoard">
        <!-- <button>EXPORT <i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i></button> -->
        <table class="scoreBoardTable table display" id="scoreBoardTable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Round</th>
              <th>Guest</th>
              <th>Computer</th>
            </tr>
            /* HERE I INSERT
            <td> WITH A JQUERY CODE*/
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <button>EXPORT <i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i></button>
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#scoreBoardTable").datatable();
});
```

I think that all it is correct but I get this:

> TypeError: $("#scoreBoardTable").datatable is not a function

Any idea? Thank for you helo!

Comment: Sounds like the path for datatables.js is incorrect.

Comment: The error says `DataTable`, the code you showed says `datatable`. Remember JS is case-sensitive.

Comment: DataTables is the folder where is datatables.min.js

Comment: I don't know show photos but folders structure it is:

CSS
HTML
js
Datatables (And into Datatables are datatables.min.js and datatables.min.css)

Answer (score 0):

To initialize DataTables plugin, use the code below:

```
$("#scoreBoardTable").DataTable();
```

or

```
$("#scoreBoardTable").dataTable();
```

See [official documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/installation#Initialising-DataTables) for more details.